# canvas Flip image and change with other

Tags: javascript, canvas, flip

I'm trying to implement a flip image with canvas, like this but the animation is weird from the middle

[image]

### update

1. This is only a part of the image,  the final result is

#### From

[image]

#### transition

[image]

#### To

[image]

but am having trouble, for I am creating a small buffer for each animation and then replaced them with a time interval

```
// globals
animations = [];
handler;
// Main canvas, the user see this
context;
canvas;

function flip(x, y, width, height) {        
    // getBuffer returns {cv: canvas, cx, context }
    var buffer = getBuffer(canvas.width, canvas.height),

        // getNextImage return a Image object ready for use
        img = getNextImage(),
        ready = false,
        interval;

    buffer.cx.drawImage(img, x, x);

    newImage = buffer.cx.getImageData(x, y, width, height);

    for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        smallBuff = getBuffer(width, height);
        scale = -(1/i);
        smallBuff.cx.translate(width / 2, 0);
        smallBuff.cx.scale(scale, 1);
        smallBuff.cx.putImageData(newImage, x, y);

        animations.push(smallBuff);
        ready = (1 === i);
    };

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Are you ready: ", ready);
        if (ready) {
            clearInterval(interval);

            handler = setInterval(function() {
                animation(x, y, width, height);
            }, 200);
        }
    }, 100);
}

function animation(x, y, width, height) {
    if(animations.length > 0) {
        var anim = animations.pop();
        anim.cx.fillstyle = '#000';
        anim.cx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
        context.drawImage(anim.cv, x, y);
        console.log("left:", animations.length);
    } else {
        clearInterval(handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle so people can easily help you find the solution?

Comment: there is already webkit why do you need to do this

Comment: @btevfik - What? Webkit and `canvas` are two different things.

Comment: @Derek can't you do this with css3

Comment: this is only a tile, my image is composed many tiles

Comment: @btevfik - CSS3 isn't supported on every browser. However `canvas` is relatively more widely supported. Furthermore maybe this is only a part of the whole content in `canvas`.

Comment: @btevfik -  I know you can do that easily with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/tEGum/ But still.

Comment: @Derek the example are not cards that means all are only one big image i wanna flip small pieces of that big image

Comment: @rkmax - I know what you are talking about now; you have a Picture A and you splitted it into pieces and flipping individual pieces combining into Picture B, right? But what is the problem here in your question?

Comment: @rkmax - I believe this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/keHkg/